# Exact location of usr/local

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

I can't seem to find the exact location of usr/local on OS X.
I want to install homebrew because I installed it in a bad way and want do do a reinstall.

Homebrew recommends installing in usr/local and I think the issue now is, that it's not installed there.

I want to cd into usr/local using Terminal but just entering `cd usr/local` doesn't work in Terminal.
Any help?

Comment: The right directory should be /usr/local, cd usr/local will get you to /Users/yourname/usr/local, which doesn't exist. "Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an absolute path like:

```
cd /usr/local
```

When you skip the first slash `/` it will work as relative, it will depend on your current location, it could work or not. If you first cd into the root path `cd /` then using `cd usr/local` would take you the the same folder.

Additionally use `pwd` if you want to output the currently directory you are in.